# Load an HTML Page Within qTip Tooltip

Tags: qtip

Im trying to load a simple html page, instead of a youtube video, using the code from this page:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/youtube#

How would i edit this code to just load a page called MyCustomPage.html?

Comment: This issue is useless since there is just a link which no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
content: {
    ajax: {
        url : 'a url'
    }
}
```

to load a webpage. [Here is the demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax).